Python requests HTTP PUT results in ChunkedEncodingError
When executing the code below, the ChunkedEncodingError is always raised. Why could this be?
    try:
        r = requests.put(
            url,
            data=payload,  # encodings.utf_8.encode(payload)[0],
            headers={
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8',
                'Accept-Encoding': '*',  # 'deflate, gzip, compress, br, zstd, identity'
            },
            auth=HTTPDigestAuth(
                access_obj['pubKey'],
                access_obj['privKey']
            ),
            stream=False
        )
    except ChunkedEncodingError as ex:
        print(f"Invalid chunk encoding {str(ex)}")

